# Simple URI rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My current .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^falsebase\.net
RewriteRule (.*) http://falsebase.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want to add on to this so I when a user enters "http://u.falsebase.net/USERNAME" into their address bar they get directed to "http://falsebase.net/profile.php?name=USERNAME".

I imagine this is pretty simple, I just have no experience with .htaccess, and after scanning through about 12 other threads that seemed similar to this, I did not get a consistent answer from any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an internal rewrite rule, not an external redirect. You don't really want your users to ever see an ugly URL like /profile.php?name=USERNAME.

So try using something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /profile.php?name=$1
```

where .+ is a pattern that matches the username.

If you know your usernames are all a-z or A-Z characters, for instance, you could tighten this up above by using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(a-zA-Z)$ /profile.php?name=$1
```

Bear in mind that having the username part of your URL as /username will catch *all* possible URLs. You might want to put these into a specific namespace, like

```
http://www.example.com/user/<username>
```

where  is the entered username, in which case you would use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/user/(.+)$ /profile.php?name=$1
```

etc.

Comment: I tried, this but it doesn't seem to work.  I am trying to add something to my current htaccess file (shown above), not replace it with something.  I want the htaccess to both redirect all www.mydomain.net -> mydomain.net (it already does this and works fine) and add the internal rewrite so mydomain.net/u/USERNAME always loads the page mydomain.net/profile.php?name=USERNAME, while still having mydomain.net/u/USERNAME appear as the URL.

Comment: Ok, so I know it's been awhile, but I found it it was my hosting service not reading my .htaccess file.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(u\.)?falsebase\.net
RewriteRule (.*) http://falsebase.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(u\.)?falsebase\.net
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ http://falsebase.net/profile.php?name=$0
```

Or if an internal redirect is possible:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(u\.)?falsebase\.net
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ profile.php?name=$0
```